# Spree Commerce: variant thumbnails

Tags: e-commerce, spree, variant

I have a product with some variants (based on different color):

[image: product]

How can I change left thumb/images for every variant (color) for products? When i want select "Green" color, for example, i'd like show green bag, when i select "Red" the red bag, etc etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I applied the following code and custom classes on my images:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".indice-0").show();
    $(document).on("change", 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
        var idcheck = ($(this).val());
        $("a.variante").hide();
      $("a.variante-"+idcheck).show();
    });
});
</script>
```